# Node.js, Docusign, and Heroku "errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."

Tags: node.js, heroku, jwt, docusignapi

I'm currently using the JWT auth flow for the docusign api. Everything works locally, but it doesn't work when deployed to Heroku. The gist is there's a webhook triggered by Copper CRM which then generates a JWT that gets traded for an access token to make the api calls to do some work finding the proper template and sending an envelope. I logged out the access token that gets generated and IT WORKS FINE MAKING THE SAME API CALL IN POSTMAN, but the api calls made through heroku give the error:

"errorCode":"AUTHORIZATION_INVALID_TOKEN","message":"The access token provided is expired, revoked or malformed."

Here's the code for generating the JWT and making the request to get the access token:

```
import jwt from 'jsonwebtoken';
import request from 'superagent';

export const createJWT = async() => {
    const iat = new Date().getTime() / 1000;
    const exp = new Date().setDate(new Date().getDate() + 2) / 1000;
    return jwt.sign({
        iss: process.env.DOCUSIGN_INTEGRATION_KEY,
        sub: process.env.DOCUSIGN_API_USERNAME,
        iat: iat,
        exp: exp,
        aud: 'account-d.docusign.com',
        scope: 'signature impersonation'
    },
        process.env.DOCUSIGN_PRIVATE_KEY,
        {
            algorithm: 'RS256'
        });
};

export const getAccessTokenFromJWT = async(jwt) => {
    const res = await request.post(`https://account-d.docusign.com/oauth/token?grant_type=urn:ietf:params:oauth:grant-type:jwt-bearer&assertion=${jwt}`)
      .catch(err => console.log(err));
    return res.body.access_token;
};
```

Here's the code for the first api call the webhook makes - the one that gives the error.

```
import request from 'superagent';
import dotenv from 'dotenv';

dotenv.config();

export const findTemplateIdByCohortName = async (cohortName, access_token) => {
    const url = `${process.env.DOCUSIGN_BASE_PATH}/v2.1/accounts/${process.env.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID}/templates?search_text=${cohortName}`;
    const result = await request.get(url)
      .set({
          Authorization: `Bearer ${access_token}`
      });
    if(result.body.envelopeTemplates) {
        return result.body.envelopeTemplates[0].templateId;
    } else {
        return null;
    }
};
```

Here's the route that handles the webhook (I'm using module import syntax):

```
import express from 'express';
import { useTemplate } from '../request/docusign/docusign-methods.mjs';
import opportunities from '../request/prosperworks/opportunities.mjs';
import people from '../request/prosperworks/people.js';
import customFields from '../request/prosperworks/custom-fields.mjs';
import { findTemplateIdByCohortName } from '../request/docusign/templates.mjs';
import { findSentEnvelopesByStudentEmail, voidEnvelope, findTemplateFromEnvelopeTemplateUri } from '../request/docusign/envelopes.mjs';
import { createJWT, getAccessTokenFromJWT } from '../request/docusign/token.mjs';

const router = express.Router();

export default router
  .post('/copper/opportunity/updated', express.json(), async (req, res, next) => {
      const { body } = req;
      console.log('webhook received', body);
      const jwt = await createJWT();
      const access_token = await getAccessTokenFromJWT(jwt);
      console.log(access_token);
      if(!Object.keys(body.updated_attributes).length) return res.send('irrelevant webhook');
      if(body.updated_attributes.custom_fields['94620'] || body.updated_attributes.stage[0] === 'Interview Scheduled' && body.updated_attributes.stage[1] === 'Accepted') {
          try {
              const opportunity = await opportunities.get(body.ids[0]);
              const cohortId = opportunity.custom_fields.find(field => field.custom_field_definition_id === 94620).value;
              const cohortName = customFields.getCohortNameById(cohortId);
              const templateId = await findTemplateIdByCohortName(cohortName);    
              const person = await people.findById(opportunity.primary_contact_id);
              const email = person.emails[0].email;
              const { name } = person;
              const sentEnvelopes = await findSentEnvelopesByStudentEmail(email, access_token);
              await Promise.all(
                sentEnvelopes.filter(envelope => {
                    return envelope.emailSubject.includes('Enrollment Agreement');
                })
                .map(envelope => {
                    if(envelope.status === 'sent') return voidEnvelope(envelope.id, access_token);
                })
              );
              const sentEnvelopesTemplates = await Promise.all(sentEnvelopes.map(envelope => {
                  return findTemplateFromEnvelopeTemplateUri(envelope.templatesUri, access_token);
              }));
              const templateAlreadyUsedCheck = sentEnvelopesTemplates.reduce((outerAcc, templateArr) => {
                  if(templateArr.reduce((innerAcc, template) => {
                      if(template.templateId === templateId) innerAcc=true;
                      return innerAcc;
                  }, false)) {
                      outerAcc=true;
                  }
                  return outerAcc;
              }, false);
              console.log(templateAlreadyUsedCheck);
              if(templateAlreadyUsedCheck) return res.send('envelope already sent');
              const envelope = await useTemplate({
                  basePath: process.env.DOCUSIGN_BASE_PATH,
                  accessToken: access_token,
                  accountId: process.env.DOCUSIGN_ACCOUNT_ID,
                  envelopeArgs: {
                      templateId: templateId,
                      signerEmail: email,
                      signerName: name
                  }
              });  
              return res.send(envelope);
          }
          catch(err) {
              console.log(err);
              next(err);
          }
      } else {
          return res.send('irrelevant webhook');
      }
  });
```

Answer (score 1):

A couple questions on this:

1. Are you using the same integration key when you try this locally vs on Heroku?
2. I noticed your env is hardcoded to `aud: 'account-d.docusign.com'`. Did you mean to use the demo env both locally and in Heroku?

My understanding here is that all of this works fine when you run locally on Postman, but after you deploy in Heroku then you see the authorization error. Is my understanding accurate?

Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

It turns out the problem was that I wasn't passing access_token to the function that makes the api call.